# Importing an AIX kernel extension file using GCC

Tags: gcc, kernel, aix, kernel-extension

I'm building a sample program using kernel extension on AIX 6.1.

Actually, I made a extension file, but I don't know how to import it.

Usually people using IBM C compiler can import this with "-bI:test.esp".
When I used this option for test program. I got the following error.

```
bash# gcc -o test_prog -bI:import test_prog.c
test_prog.c: In function 'main':
gcc: unrecognized option '-bI:question.esp'
ld: 0711-317 error: unrecognized symbol: .question
collect2: ld returned 8 exit status
```

Comment: Are you sure that example is correct? You claim to have used -bI:import but GCC says you used -bI:question.esp. also shouldn't it be ".exp" not ".esp"? And what does "dun" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a linker option so to tell GCC to forward it to the linker use `-Wl,-bI:question.esp` or `-Xlinker -bI:question.esp`

Comment: thank you very much. I finally linked. but I have problem still here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749612/errors-when-i-excute-aix-kernel-extension-program